# How to uncheck a multiple selector and perform the subtraction with js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have three drop-downs. Each time you select an item from the dropdown-list, it is added to the total value and it is displayed below in a label. When the user clicks on the 'X' of the label, the label is removed and the value of the item should be substracted from the dropdown-list. However, it isn't substracted.

This is link where I have the form:

https://codepen.io/MoisosxD/pen/gOPpXGQ

You see to remove the label I have it like this:

```
onclick="desmarcarspan1();"
```

dentro del js así:

```
function desmarcarspan1(){
        var total = document.getElementById("totalGeneral");
        var total1 = new Array(total);
        var NuevoTotal = total.textContent;
        console.log(total.textContent);
        var ans10 = document.getElementById("ans-10");
        ans10.style.display = "none";
    }
```

But I have not done anything else I do not know how to do the subtraction and to uncheck the selector.

Comment: so you want the price  to go back if the dropdown is deselected? your code worked for me except, the dropdown in the middle didnt get unchecked. is that the problem here?

Comment: @HishamBawa You can click on the labels at the bottom. I think what the user wants is that if you click on the label the element gets unchecked the price of the item gets substracted from the total price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the function sumValues() global, you can just decheck the dropdown-element and call the function then:

sumValues():

```
function sumValues() {
    const inputArray = document.querySelectorAll('input.itemTotalNeto');
    console.log(inputArray);
    const totalValue = document.querySelector('#totalGeneral');
    let cboxVals = 0;
    inputArray.forEach(element => cboxVals += element.checked ? parseInt(element.value, 10) : 0);
    totalValue.innerHTML = cboxVals;
}
```

desmarcspan1():

```
function desmarcarspan1() {

    //decheck the dropdown-element:
    document.getElementById('check-1').checked = false;

    //sum up values again
    sumValues();

    var total = document.getElementById("totalGeneral");
    var total1 = new Array(total);
    var NuevoTotal = total.textContent;
    console.log(total.textContent);
    const totalValue = document.querySelector('#totalGeneral');
    var ans1 = document.getElementById("ans-1");
    ans1.style.display = "none";
}
```

See this working example:
https://codepen.io/PhoenixFlight/pen/eYJNMYm